# Workbook.Open Code Stops Running Midway Through

Tags: excel, vba

*Code at the bottom*

I'm working on an Update System for the AddIn I created for my team to use at work.

I created a mini 'Helper' file. When it's opened, it does the following:

1) Saves itself to Application.StartupPath

2) Uninstalls the current version of the AddIn

3) Copies the most recent version of the AddIn from the Network Drive to the local ADDINS folder

4) Reinstalls the new version of the AddIn

5) Closes itself (the Helper file)

This way whenever someone opens Excel, they will always have the most recent version of the AddIn.

If someone opens Excel from scratch, or they open the Helper file directly, all of the above works as expected. However, when I try and upgrade FROM the ADDIN, it doesn't.

There's an 'Update' button on the AddIn. Click that button (basically) opens the Helper file. The idea being that if the Helper file is opened, it will automatically Update the AddIn.

However the Helper code (which is all contained in Workbook_Open) stops running at: *AddIns(sAddInName).Installed = False*

There's no error or anything. If I step into the code, after that line is run, the AddIn runs its BeforeClose() code, and after that's done, it just stops, as if there was no code after it (although there is).

**Relevant Code**

*Helper Code - Logging/Error Handling Removed*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'Load Master Path and AddIn Path
    Dim sAddInPath As String, sAddInMasterPath As String
    sAddInPath = Environ$("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Addins\TAAA.xlam"
    sAddInMasterPath = "...\TAAA - AddIn.xlam"

    'If TAAA Helper Isn't Auto-Open, Set to Auto-Open
    If ThisWorkbook.Path <> Application.StartupPath Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Application.StartupPath & "\" &     ThisWorkbook.Name
    End If

    'If AddIn Is Available Then Uninstall It
    If bAddInAvailableToInstall("TAAA") Then

        AddIns("TAAA").Installed = False
```

-------- IT STOPS AFTER THE ABOVE LINE ---------

```
    End If

    'Copying Master AddIn to Local Path
    FileCopy sAddInMasterPath, sAddInPath

    'If AddIn Is Unavailable Then Add It
    If Not bAddInAvailableToInstall("TAAA") Then
        Dim myAddIn As AddIn
        Set myAddIn = Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:=sAddInPath,     CopyFile:=True)
    End If

    'Installing AddIn
    AddIns("TAAA").Installed = True

    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a bootleg workaround in case anyone wants a subpar solution to this problem.

**Bootleg Workaround**

I took all the code that runs after AddIns(sAddInName).Installed = False and copied it to a new procedure WorkbookOpen_Part2.

Right before the AddIns(sAddInName).Installed = False line, I added an Application.OnTime for Now+1 second to run WorkbookOpen_Part2.

Then, right after AddIns(sAddInName).Installed = False I cancel the Application.OnTime call.

This way if the code doesn't do its weird stop, then the OnTime is instantly canceled and never runs. If the code does do its weird stop, then the OnTime resumes the rest of the code a second later.

```
mdNextCheckTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime mdNextCheckTime, "WorkbookOpen_Part2"

AddIns("TAAA").Installed = False

CancelCheck 'This cancels the Application.OnTime
```